# getting ORA-00933 while executing SQL query using ExecuteStoreQuery method

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework

I am getting ORA-00933 error while executing SQL query using ExecuteStoreQuery method in C#.

Here is the code:

```
public IEnumerable<Administrator> FilterEmployees(string name)
        {
            Context db = new Context();
            string query = "SELECT USER_ROLES.USER_ROLES_ID, EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEES.SURNAME_1, EMPLOYEES.SURNAME_2, ROLES.NAME FROM USER_ROLES" +
                                                            "INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON USER_ROLES.USER_ID = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID" +
                                                            "INNER JOIN ROLES ON USER_ROLES.ROLE_ID = ROLES.ROLE_ID" +
                                                            "WHERE ROLES.IS_INTRANET_ONLY = 'N' AND EMPLOYEES.FULL_EMPLOYEE_NAME LIKE '%Yuriy%'";
            List<Administrator> employees;
            return db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Administrator>(query, "employees", System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
        }
```

The query is fine(tested on Oracle SQL Developer)

Comment: Please tell us the full error

Comment: _The query is fine(tested on Oracle SQL Developer)_ Are you sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're concatenating strings, and there is no whitespace between the last word of one string and the beginning of the next. Leading to this query being executed : (formatting mine)

```
SELECT 
    USER_ROLES.USER_ROLES_ID, 
    EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, 
    EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
    EMPLOYEES.SURNAME_1, 
    EMPLOYEES.SURNAME_2, 
    ROLES.NAME FROM USER_ROLESINNER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON USER_ROLES.USER_ID = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_IDINNER JOIN ROLES ON USER_ROLES.ROLE_ID = ROLES.ROLE_IDWHERE ROLES.IS_INTRANET_ONLY = 'N' AND EMPLOYEES.FULL_EMPLOYEE_NAME LIKE '%Yuriy%'
                              ^ Problem is here                                                 ^and here                                             ^and here
```

Add a space to the end of each of the strings.

Comment: yes, it where the spaces. Didn't think about them when I copied the query from Oracle Developer, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**The query is not correct**-

While writing such queries inline, you must be sure that there should be proper **spaces** between the keywords-

You should debug the code and see what **query** variable returns

I think you should modify your query as follows (by giving spaces at the end of each line)

```
string query = "SELECT USER_ROLES.USER_ROLES_ID, EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_NAME, EMPLOYEES.SURNAME_1, EMPLOYEES.SURNAME_2, ROLES.NAME FROM USER_ROLES " +
      "INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES ON USER_ROLES.USER_ID = EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID " +
      "INNER JOIN ROLES ON USER_ROLES.ROLE_ID = ROLES.ROLE_ID " +
      "WHERE ROLES.IS_INTRANET_ONLY = 'N' AND EMPLOYEES.FULL_EMPLOYEE_NAME LIKE '%Yuriy%'";
```